# Android reading cookies

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies

Hey, how can I read a value of a cookie?

Example:

```
String cs = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie();
System.out.println("Cookies string:  "+cs);
```

This will give me a string which has to be parsed with split on ';' and '='. Is there a "cookie string reader" or smth? Is there any other way of reading the value of only one particular cookie in the webview?

Thx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I suggest that you parse the string into an Array yourself. That would then be something along these lines in standard Java:

```
String[] x = Pattern.compile(";").split(CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie());
```

Now you have an Array of name - value pairs, which you can further parse and then store.