# Android webview read cookies

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview, android-webview

I have the following code to display a webpage in a webview:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://the.url.com");
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Now I want to read cookie of the webview. Is this possible?

Comment: `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://the.url.com")` . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getCookie(java.lang.String)

Comment: It is working and in the page are two cookies. How can I select only first or second cookie and its value.

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840966/android-reading-cookies

Comment: these two cookies associated to same url?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It was a quite late , but it might help someone

you can get the cookie value by this

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){     
    String CookieValue = null;

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);   
    if(cookies != null){
        String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
        for (String ar1 : temp ){
            if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
                String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
                CookieValue = temp1[1];
            }
        }              
     }
     return CookieValue;    
}
```

### Edit

Point to notice:

If you are loading URL like `http://sitedomain.com` (without `www`), the `siteName` with `www` will not work with this method.

Comment: Cookie name doesn't need to be pass in capital letters!! @NicolaeSurdu

Comment: Sorry, was to tired to check history. Edited the answer to reflect the current status.

Comment: A good solution, but not right. You shouldn't split a cookie with "=", because in a right part it may also contain "=". So, you should separate left and right parts only once with `split("=", 2)`.

Comment: I think you need a break after finding it, if you want to retrieve the first one only.

Comment: I need help to get cookies for url      (  https://www.dailymotion.com/   ) which contains www