# Browser cookies

Tags: android, cookies, browser

My task is to get cookies from browsers installed on Android device including Android native browser. I want to ask if there is any way to get cookies from the browsers. Any help or links regarding the details will be of good.

Comment: please have a look on this [Android webview read cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654631/android-webview-read-cookies)

Comment: @user3110424 I want to get cookies from android native browser, not from webview integrated in my own app.

Comment: Since it is not clear if you want to do this via an app or a site browsed on the native browser, I am voting to close as unclear (and the question is two years old and abandoned at this point). My guess would be that without root permissions either approach would not work.