# How to get all cookie data form webview android?

Tags: android, cookies, android-webview

I used `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)` but It just return "cookieName=cookieValue". I want to get additional cookie data like path,expiration date...

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String CookieName){     
String CookieValue = null;

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);   
if(cookies != null){
    String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
    for (String ar1 : temp ){
        if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
            String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
            CookieValue = temp1[1];
        }
    }              
 }
 return CookieValue;
```

}

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241864/4862911